# Can a com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException be caused by trying to insert too many new records in one transaction within Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, websphere, dao

I am trying to update a DB2 table using a DAO update's method. The code works flawlessly when I'm adding a single record, if it is simply updating record(s), or updating and adding a single record. But if the code builds multiple new records, a com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException is thrown and the changes aren't committed to the database. The primary key for the objects aren't duplicated except for the new records which all have '0' for the data member that is treated as the primary key. Am I on the right track with how this error could be inadvertently caused, or no? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If new records have a value of 0 for a data member that is a treated as a primary key, then you will be able to insert only the first one.

Your statement saying PK for the objects aren't duplicate except.... sounds like a contradictory statement to me.

Can you clarify?